# How can I copy a webpage in qwebkit?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qtwebview

Lets say I have two qwebview widgets .lets call it W1 and W2, I then set the urls with

```
W1->setUrl("someUrlHere");.
```

Both pages has separate css files.

Then I'll change the background on some element in w1 with

```
.setStyleProperty("background-color",qColor(255,0,0));
```

All good so far and the background changes to red.

now I want to replace the page in w2 with w1 (without using `.seturl`), including the stylesheet for w1. Then I want to be able to change the colors on each of them without affecting the other

I've tried `.toHtml()` and `.sethtml()`, but this will only copy the html (of course) and thus all styles from w1 is lost.

Also tried many other ways, including `.setpage`, `.clone` etc etc...
 but it seems to only change the html, or it change the pointers to it, (so if I do changes to w1 it only affect w2 and w1 can't be touched anymore etc..)

Is it possible to do this? also, is it possible to do it without needing widgets for each?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this thread is still active but I stumbled upon it while looking for answers for a QtWebkit problem I'm facing. Anyway...

```
void QNAMProxy::HandleFinished( QNetworkReply* reply ) {
    if( reply->error( )) {
        // Something went wrong
    } else {
        QUrl url = reply->url( );
        //TODO Parse the URL to create your local path
        QFile file( "Parsed local file name" );
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            // Some problem with creating the file to write
        } else {
            file.write( reply->readAll( ));
            file.close( );
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to save the page as html

```
webPage->currentFrame()->toHtml() => QString
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer,  but using `toHtml()` seems to only take the html, and not any style.